# Escapar barra invertida en parámetro de una consulta GET en .Net Core 1.0

Tags: asp.net-core, http-get, urlencoding

Tengo un API REST implementada en .Net Core, en lo que todo funcionaba perfecto hasta que se agregaron registros importados en los cuales el campo que se usaba como parámetro un alfanumérico sin caracteres raros:

```
COD1213
http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/subproyectos/subproyectos/COD1213
```

el inconveniente surge porque los nuevos registros que se migraron usan un campo que contiene al medio una barra invertidas:

```
2017/205
```

lo que produce que la correspondiente petición quede no valida, aun escapando `/` con `%2f`, net core me esta tomando como iguales las siguientes peticiones

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/subproyectos/subproyectos/COD1213
http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/subproyectos/subproyectos%2fCOD1213
```

Dejo el codigo

```
namespace WebAPIApplication.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/subproyectos/[controller]")]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    public class SubProyectosController : Controller
    { 
        // codigo no relevante

        [HttpGet("{CodSubProyecto}")]
        public string Get(string CodSubProyecto)
        {
        // aquí es donde da problemas la barra invertida
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sería factible que "escapes" ese caracter reemplazandolo por una secuencia y hacer el proceso inverso del lado del server?

Comment: Es factible, es la primera solución que se nos ocurrió pero no se si es rentable es lo que estamos discutiendo en el proyecto, ya que estamos bastante avanzados y creció mucho la app, otra cosa que me olvide ese dato se muestra en el frontend en ciertas pantallas, por lo que el cambio que sugieres requeriría  tocar ambos.

Comment: Sería cambiarlo solo para transmisión.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías sustituir en tu URL la `/` por `%252F` para así escapar de la propia "decodificación" de la WebAPI, por lo que ya en tu controlador de WebAPI obtendras el preciado `%2F`.

Me imagino que la petición sería algo del tipo: 
`http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/subproyectos/subproyectos/COD/1213`

Enconces la sustituimos por:
`http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/subproyectos/subproyectos/COD%252F1213`

Para conseguir así que en nuestro ApiController nos llegue la información como:
`COD%2F1213`

Una vez aquí solo tendríamos que decodificar el valor del string de esta manera para conseguir el valor que deseamos:

```
[HttpGet("{CodSubProyecto}")]
public string Get(string CodSubProyecto)
{
    CodSubProyecto = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(CodSubProyecto)
}
```

**EDITO**

Para poder hacer eso necesitarás editar el web.config de tu WebAPI para permitir el doble escape. Necesitaras poner estos valores como se muestran:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestPathInvalidCharacters=""/>                
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: si es una alternativa que estaba revisando, pero también agrega posibles problemas de seguridad